# Convert string with special characters to json string

Tags: c#, json

Here the message that i'm retrieving from a file.

> "Before you can use Online Map, you must fill in the Online Map Setup window.\See Setting Up "Online Map" in Help.","Avant de pouvoir utiliser Online Map, vous devez compléter la fenêtre Configuration "Online Map".\Consultez la section Configuration d'Online Map dans l'Aide."

I want to convert my string to a valid Json String then add it to JsonObject.

I'm using JsonToken to read my string then i add every JsonToken to JsonObject but when i got a string with special characters i got an error.

Here my code:

```
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Myfile.txt"))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string ln;
            JsonObject Obj = new JsonObject();
            while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(ln));
                JToken Token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                Obj.Add(counter.ToString(), Token);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Here the error :
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmHX2.png)

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: And what error you got?

Comment: Please, share your json as well. Which special character do you have?